# Свёртка тензора ранга 2 с тензором ранга 4 в TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Для решения одной физической задачи (без нейронных сетей) использую TensorFlow, исключительно как инструмент для вычислений. Так вот, у меня есть тензор ранга 2 (назовём его исходным) размерностью 10х10 и тензор ранга 4 (назовём его ядром) размерностью 2х2х2х2. Так вот, мне нужно как бы ходить по исходному тензору и вычислить свёртку исходного тензора, но у же с размерностью 2х2 с ядром 2х2х2х2. То есть, вычислил свёртку первого блока 2х2 с ядром, результат положил обратно, взял следующий блок 2х2 свернул с ядром, результат положил обратно и т.д. по всему исходному тензору с размерностью 10х10.

Может кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной задачей и подскажет какими операциями в TF это всё можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо!